# why my release not belong to me

Tags: ros, bloom-release

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hi there:

i released a rplidar_python driver last year, but when i check it today, it not belong to me any more, could anyone help me on this problem? thanks advance! appreciate for helping!  here is the link
http://www.ros.org/browse/details.php?distro=indigo&name=rplidar_python

> rplidar_python (indigo)
>
> Author(s):
>
> Maintainer(s): turtlebot2
>
> License: TODO
>
> Source:
> https://github.com/DinnerHowe/rplidar_python.git
>
> Dependencies:
>
> Description: The rplidar_python
> package

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/258883/why-my-release-not-belong-to-me/) by [DinnerHowe](https://answers.ros.org/users/26306/dinnerhowe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 188 on 2017-04-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [NEngelhard](https://answers.ros.org/users/18581/nengelhard/) on 2017-04-10**:
Wild guess: the page is created automatically from your package.xml and there is no author-tag but just a maintainer-tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at the source here: https://github.com/DinnerHowe/rplidar_python/blob/master/package.xml

It looks like you never filled out the author tag in your package.xml file. Just add something like the following line in there:

```
<author>DinnerHowe</author>
```

---

Originally posted by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) with karma: 3460 on 2017-04-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DinnerHowe](https://answers.ros.org/users/26306/dinnerhowe/) on 2017-04-10**:
thanks a lot, i have never notice that before